# With SpringDoc OpenAPI, Double and other non-primitives numbers are not marked as nullable

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

We are using SpringDoc OpenAPI with SpingBoot 2.3 and WebFlux and have Swagger UI on top of it (more precisely springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui 1.4.8).

Lately, we noticed that there is no way to differentiate a nullable / optional number (Double) from a primitive (double).

For example, the following class

```
@With
@Value
@Builder
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class CurrencyBalanceDto {
    double balance;
    Double hardCapping;
}
```

Results in the following OpenAPI Schema

```
"CurrencyBalanceDto": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "balance": {
            "type": "number",
            "format": "double"
        },
        "hardCapping": {
            "type": "number",
            "format": "double"
        }
    }
}
```

Based on https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#schemaNullable, I would expect the hardCapping property to have `"nullable": true`

Answer (score 2):

The quote from [the documentation](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.2.md#schemaNullable) from the provided link:

> nullable  boolean Allows sending a null value for the defined schema. **Default value is false**.

So by default, all fields are not nullable. You need explicitly set a field as nullable either by using the annotations like `@Null`, `@Nullable` or with `@Schema(nullable = true)`

Comment: While, I agree that the OpenAPI spec states that by default value if not nullable, SpringDoc-OpenAPI is an implementation of that spec specifically for Spring. In Spring, everything is nullable unless the @NotNull from java validation. Hence, I find it odd if I need to add an annotation to specify that this field is nullable just for Swagger.

Comment: SpringDoc as implementation tries to strictly follow the specification.
You could also try to ask this question here https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues but I'm pretty sure that the answer will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The springdoc-openapi library does not mark values as `nullable` by default; it will only do so if something specific tells it to do so (e.g. [`@Schema(nullable = true)`](https://javadoc.io/static/io.swagger.core.v3/swagger-annotations/2.1.10/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/media/Schema.html#nullable--)).  This isn't ideal in my personal opinion, as it introduces a discrepancy between what the OpenAPI description claims is allowable and what actually is allowable.

That being said, even if it did, arguably it should automatically mark `balance` as nullable in this case.  If the `CurrencyBalanceDto` type were only used as a response object, then yes, it would be guaranteed to never be null.  However, Jackson by default allows allows deserialization of primitive values from null:, in this case the default for the given primitive type will be used instead of null (`0` for `int`, `0.0` for `double`, `false` for `boolean`, etc.).

Because Jackson allows nulls for primitive values, it is in fact therefore *valid* by default for a `null` value to be passed as a primitive field of a request object .  Without additional context, it would be impossible for springdoc-openapi to determine that such a field should be nullable.

### Example

In your specific case, a null `balance` could be successfully passed to e.g. a `POST` endpoint that took a `CurrencyBalanceDto`:

```http
POST /currency/balance HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 2

{}
```

This object would be received by the Spring controller as a `CurrencyBalanceDto` with `balance` of `0.0` and `hardCapping` of `null`.